# php://input xml received incomplete

Tags: php, xml

I am receiving an incomplete data for `php://input` when passing data to my PHP backend via POST request. I am sure that I pass the data properly because I inspect it in [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). I use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to send a data request to my backend.
The thing is that I am receiving the XML I want to post to my backend as incomplete, it is cut from the particular line below it. Is there any PHP directive in the PHP.ini which set the number of character I am able to pass?

My `post_max_size = 64M` is this.

Answer (score 1):

No I've never seen any php.ini directive that limit the number of characters that you can send via a post, not other than memory_limit,
upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

the most common error you are likely to get here is a character that is not encoded properly, typically the amper sign "&" or one of its variance,

also you might get some improvment by using different Content-Types such as "multipart/form-data", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "text/plain"

Now you want to compare what you get from php://input vs $_POST, 
when you use php://input  your at a lower level, you are probably using fread() or fgets() and these functions only read a certain number or characters at the once, so you either have to specify the second parameter (the length) of these functions or you have to loop on those functions until you have read all the data

maybe something like this 
    `$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $contents = '';
    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }`

now it depends what you are doing with this data and in most cases using $_POST is your best option